# fetchAll returns int columns as string instead of integer

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using `fetchAll` for a sql query.
but when I use `gettype` function it always returns string.

```
$this->QueryID->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
print_r(gettype($data[0]['Num'])); //it returns string.
```

but its a `int` column.

Comment: Your title was a bit misleading. fetchAll only returns arrays :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Is there a better choice?

Comment: Pardon me? Better than what and in which way?

Comment: I want to have type of values when I get my result from query.

Comment: Then you may refer to the solution provided in the topic pinned at the top of your question